# Public Transit update interval & flight departure time data

Tags: here-api

First question:

We want to use here.com APIs. We have a question on how frequently the API endpoint "All Next Departures from a Location" (https://transit.api.here.com/v3/multiboard/by_geocoord.json) is updated.
We want to real-time departure times around a certain location in order to inform the customers using the service.
How often is this endpoint updated?

Second question:

In the documention, there is a list of "Transit Modes" one of the modes is "flight" is it possible to get fight data via the here.com APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Route Section update provides Real Time information of a particular route section.

```
https://transit.api.here.com/v3/sectionupdate.json
?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}
&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}
&ctx={Context from one of 'Connections/Connection/Sections/Sec' elements in previous transit route response}
&graph=1
```

The response to the request contains the following information blocks:

- a single transit connection containing a single segment
- the connection includes the following information: departure time, real-time information about delays or disruptions
- an operator who runs the service, including operator code, operator name and links to operator websites, if any.

You can read more about it in the developer site : https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/example-update-section-in-route.html

There is also an example provided : https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/public_transit/section-update

Coverage for Real Time Routing can be looked upon here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/transit/topics/coverage-information.html

Flight schedule is currently not provided in Public Transit API